# Visualizing large supervised learning data set using PCA and scatter3 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-visualization

How can I visualize a data set with a large amount of features using scatter3 plot in matlab. I already have it reduce to three features using PCA, but how do I get it to show up in different colours depending on if the y value (or labelled value)  for the corresponding row is 1 or 0?
P.S. PCA return a [675 x 3] matrix, which is the 675 examples in the data set, with the first 3 principle components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too up-to-date on my matlab, but I believe you can do it by firstly setting `hold on` then looping through and plotting each row of your matrix using plot3, and setting the colour based on the label. eg

```
hold on
for i=1:675,
    if (label == 1)
        plot3(mat(i,1), mat(i,2), mat(i,3), '-xr');
    elseif (label == 2)
        plot3(mat(i,1), mat(i,2), mat(i,3), '-og');
    elseif (label == 3)
        plot3(mat(i,1), mat(i,2), mat(i,3), '-b');
    end
end
hold off
```

This may need some tweaking though, since it is a while since I have used Matlab. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. Did have to do some tweaking but I got the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
% Create some data to represent the results of PCA
x = rand(675,3); y = randi([0,1],675,1);

% Plot with markers of size 10
scatter3(x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3),10,y)
```

A bit easier than the loop and if statement approach suggested elsewhere.